# Background color for matRipple

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

If I use `<span matRipple matRippleColor="red">Text</span>`, everything becomes red and I can't read my text anymore.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cep1hh?file=src/app/ripple-overview-example.html)

Is there a way to make only the background red but not the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use position absolute and z-index: 1 for text value

```
<span matRipple matRippleColor="red">
  <span style="position:absolute; z-index:1">Text</span>
</span>
```